# discord.py / disnake.py / pycord.py voice mute

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I want to mute a user in a voice channel without kicking them.

This does not fit:

1.`await member.add_roles(role_mute)`
For this to work, the user needs to be kicked from the voice chat.

I tried to update the permissions in the voice channel, in the hope that this would help

```
await channel.set_permissions(role, overwrite=disnake.PermissionOverwrite(speak=False))
await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=disnake.PermissionOverwrite(speak=False))
```

but it did not help

2.`await member.edit(mute=True)`
It works, but I saw on one server the mutes were not red.
[red mute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdSRi.png)
I think there was used `await member.add_roles(role_mute)`and something else, but I don't know what
[gray mute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq9gt.png)

What could it be?

*for "mr beam"*

[*When assigning a role*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EHHU.png)

[*If the user re-enters the channel*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70P4Z.png)

*I want it to look like the last screenshot, but without kicking the user
from the channel*

Comment: I’m confused cos you tagged 3 different libraries bruh. At this point the 3 libraries greatly vary from each other

Comment: I used all these libraries in turn, but did not find a solution. It will be good if it is one of the listed libraries, but if it is some other, then it will suit me

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to mute a defined user, you can do something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
     await user.edit(mute=True)
```

If you want to give a role to a user that blocks their ability to speak in **any** voice channel, you can do this:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member): 
      role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Muted") # You'll have to create this role. 
      await user.add_roles(role)
      await ctx.send("Some message")
```

When creating the role in your Discord, ensure it has the `Speak` perm deactivated, like [this](https://prnt.sc/rkch2lAw9j0S).

To answer the final bit of your query. **Grey** microphones are when a user has muted themselves, and **red** are when a server admin has muted them, aka a "server mute". If the user cannot speak in that channel, they may also have either a grey or a red mic *(as pictured)*.

Comment: I wrote it all in my message...

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation to answer the second part of your query - however, the solutions provided do solve the problem you appear to be facing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't solve the problem. I updated the question and explained why. Perhaps you know more ways to mute a user in a voice channel

Comment: You cannot make the user mute themselves, which is what the grey mic indicates. If you use my second solution, you can add a role to a user which will stop them from talking in the channel, or you can server mute them using the first solution. You **cannot** locally mute a user - only the user can do this.

Comment: I saw with my own eyes that this is possible, but I do not have access to the code

Comment: I will repeat this for the last time you **cannot** locally mute a user without being the user themselves. You can restrict their ability to speak by changing the perms of the channel, adding a role to the user which restricts them from `speaking` in **any** voice channels or **server muting** them. 

If this explanation, along with my answer, does not solve **your** problem, then I'm sorry, but I cannot help any further.

Comment: I showed you an example that when a user is muted through a role, his "gray" microphone is on, if this is done manually, "Red" will be on. But in the first case, for this to work, the user needs to be moved to another voice channel and back. I want to make it so that I need to transfer it to another voice channel. I need to somehow update the rights of a user in a voice channel without excluding him from that channel

Comment: That's overcomplicating a simple problem.

Comment: I found out that it depends on "suppress=True/False" in member.voice  (return VoiceState). But I don't know how to edit it.

Comment: of documentation discord    Modify User Voice State
PATCH/guilds/{guild.id}/voice-states/{user.id}
Updates another user's voice state.

JSON Params FIELD TYPE DESCRIPTION
channel_id snowflake the id of the channel the user is currently in
suppress? boolean toggles the user's suppress state

Comment: If you were to go along the adding role method, you could just `await member.move_to(None)` *(change none to the channel you want)* then move them back to the previous voice channel. If you want to disconnect the user, just keep `await member.move_to(None)` as it is.

Comment: I found a non-obvious way to update user permissions after collecting almost every user log that was possible. That helped